# How to change scale of multiple rasters to same scale

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to determine how to change the scale of multiple rasters in R to the same scale.

For example, I have two `large rasterlayers` one ranges from 0 to 6 and one ranges from 0 to 0.8. I would like to rescale both of them and make them both be from 0 to 1. Is their a formula to apply to all the cells of a rasters to rescale them or even make the logarithmic scale?

Comment: Provide an example to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `RStoolbox` R package to rescale a RasterLayer. This is the easy way I know without having to define you own function to reescale. You should loop this function through your RasterLayers. I asume your rasters are in `originalRasterList`

`xmin`, `xmax` are the interval of values of the image.
`ymin`, `ymax` are the new interval.

```
library(RStoolbox)

originalRasterList # list containing your rasters
rescaledRasterList <- list() # empty list to fill

for(i in 1:length(originalRasterList){
  rescaledRasterList[[i]] <- rescaleImage(originalRasterList[[i]], 
                                          xmin=min(originalRasterList[[i]]), xmax=max(originalRasterList[[i]]), 
                                          ymin=0, ymax=1)}
```